# Updating Excel Header with Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have a macro that creates PDF files from a data sheet in Excel.  Another sheet in Excel is an invoice template.  The macro fills in different cells on the template sheet and saves the results as a PDF file.  The template sheet has a header that needs to be updated each time based on the vendor.  I have the code below that updates the header.  It works when I step through the code but not when I run the macro.

I'm not sure why.  Any suggestions to get this to work would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks....

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False

Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.LeftHeader = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.CenterHeader = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.CenterHeader = Header1 & Chr(10) & Header2 & Chr(10) & Header3
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.RightHeader = "Page &P of &N"
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.LeftFooter = _
        " ©  2013 Proprietary and Confidential   Reproduction/Distribution Prohibited "
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.CenterFooter = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.RightFooter = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.Zoom = 91
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = False
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
Worksheets("PrintInvoice").PageSetup.FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""

Application.PrintCommunication = True

    Sleep 2000
```

Comment: What means `...but not when I run the macro.`? You have an error?

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak......What I mean is when push the button to run the entire macro.  The update header code is just a piece of the macro.  There is no error message.  It doesnt update the header.  I I have some fields on another sheet that the user enters info and the macro picks that up and is supposed to revise the header.  currently, it's not updating and keeps the header from the last run

Comment: Did you try putting a Breakpoint at the beginning of this piece of code, to be sure that it is parsed by your full code? It looks not showing problems...

Comment: @Shaves If it `It doesn't update the header.` I may assume that nothing is picked up at this part: `I I have some fields on another sheet that the user enters info and the macro picks that up and is supposed to revise the header.` In order not to read the tea-leaves - it's better that you share the whole code, or at least involved part.

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak....I read something about this line"Application.PrintCommunication = False"  causing issues.  Once I removed it, my code updated the header.  Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some information that pointed me to the "Application.PrintCommunication = False" line as the cause of the issue. Once I removed it, my code updated the header.